# can I add agent/extension to aks node in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

nodes in nodepool have default agents installed.

Questions :
1. can I add agent/extensions on node ?
2. if yes, is it recommended/compatible ?

coulnt find anything on Google about aks node extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually extension is not supported for AKS nodes. Take a look at the troubleshooting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-use-custom-vm-extensions):

> AKS is a managed service, and manipulation of the IaaS resources is
>   not supported. To install custom components, etc. please leverage the
>   kubernetes APIs and mechanisms. For example, leverage DaemonSets to
>   install required components.

If you want to manage the nodes as you want, you'd better use the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine). Maybe it's a better choice for you.

Comment: I would like to change the some settings like ulimit of nodes in kubernetes node group. Is it possible? Does your answer is relevant for my use case